# Неверное взятие значений функцией

Tags: функции, классы

Вот мой код:

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self, name, hp, damage):
        self.name = name
        self.hp = hp
        self.damage = damage


class Enemy:
    def __init__(self, nameq, hpq, damageq):
        self.name1 = nameq
        self.hp1 = hpq
        self.damage1 = damageq


class Room(Player, Enemy):
    def __init__(self, name, hp, damage, nameq, hpq, damageq):
        super().__init__(name, hp, damage)
        super().__init__(nameq, hpq, damageq)

    def fight(self):
        print(self.hp)
        print(self.damage)
        print(self.hp - self.damage)



Swordsman = Room('Swordsman', 100, 10, 'Orc', 80, 8)
Swordsman.fight()
```

По идее должно выводиться '100', '10', '90'(так как игрок бьет сам себя), но выводится '80', '8', '72'(то есть действие выполняет противник, а не игрок),т.е. вторые значения, что неверно. Если же я заменю hp на hpq(как должно быть для верной работы),  то вылазит эта ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/munty/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/Class Swordsman.py", line 28, in <module>
    Swordsman.fight()
  File "C:/Users/munty/PycharmProjects/pythonProject2/Class Swordsman.py", line 21, in fight
    print(self.hpq)
AttributeError: 'Room' object has no attribute 'hpq'
```

С super работаю впервые. Пытался обойти это разными способами, что успел найти в интернете, но всё время различные ошибки, поэтому вернулся к этому этапу, так как тут хоть и криво, но работает.
Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вам кажется что ваши замыслы понятны всем, но спешу Вас огорчить: это не так. То что Вы пишете `по идее` не рассказав о самой идее опрометчиво. Допустим, я все же понял Вашу идею, но мне крайне не нравится Ваше решение, почему? - потому что оно режет заживо ООП и все что с ним связано. Нельзя инициализировать родительский класс дважды! Это как дважды родиться. Наследовать комнату от игроков, все равно что наследовать машину от водителя. Вам следует разобраться в ООП и почитать внимательнее про `super()._init_()` и после этого писать код. То что`хоть криво, но работает` не должно успокаивать

Comment: можете начать с чтения этой [статьи](https://tirinox.ru/super-python/)

Comment: @DaniilLoban , в видео, откуда я увидел про super делали именно так, но с одним классом, поэтому я и не понимаю, почему таким образом я ломаю ООП. Я - начинающий программист, так что уж простите, что мой код столь плох. В данном коде я лишь ищу решения своей более глобальной проблемы. Спасибо за статью, изучу и приму к сведению, но можете ли вы сказать ответ на главный мой вопрос? Или для этого недостаточно сведений в статье?

Comment: в двух словах у Вас герои перепутаны за счет этих вывертов, поэтому итог не удивителен, наверно прочитав статью что-то усвоите, это уже зависит от Вас, Успехов в освоении!

Comment: можете добавить принт в инициализации классов с их названиями и увидите, что так как Вы пишете писать нельзя у Вас будет либо `Enemy Enemy` либо `Player Player` но не `Enemy Player` и не   `Player Enemy`

Comment: @DaniilLoban понял вас, спасибо. Надеюсь смогу исправить. Не к столу сказано, до сдачи проекта месяц остался, а из-за проблем с выводом не могу доделать игру

Comment: ну во-первых месяц это довольно неплохой срок, хотя все зависит от масштабов игры и ее реализации, а во-вторых у Вас проблема не с выводом - так бы объяснял "человек играющий в игру" но не программист, у Вас проблема с архитектурой самого проекта, ну а конкретно с ООП - браться писать игру не понимая основ, рисковое дело, ну и понятно тут вряд ли кто-то будет писать код за Вас, хотя бы потому что ее можно написать по-разному.

Comment: Исходя из Вашего кода вообще нельзя понять почему у Вас атакует по факту комната (room) а не игрок, какое отношение вообще комната может иметь к бойцам? В моем понимании комната может их содержать внутри, а драться или нет уже решают сами бойцы, ну или правила игры — некий класс логики, который будет определять кто и когда и при каких условиях атакует или делает что-то другое. Тема игрописания слишком обширна, даже для полноценного ответа на этой площадке, не говоря о комментариях.